# Finding the Closest Midpoint between Two Points on an Interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

Say you are given two points $a$ and $b$ on the interval $[0, 1)$.  Finding their midpoint $m_1$ is quite simple by just averaging $a$ and $b$.  However, since this is an interval, you can imagine another midpoint $m_2$ at a distance of 0.5 from this midpoint.  I'm wondering how you could determine which midpoint $m$ is closest to the points $a$ and $b$?  You can get $m_1$ and $m_2$ from these equations, where $\operatorname{frac}$ is the fractional part function.

$$
m_1 = \frac{a + b}{2} \\
m_2 = \operatorname{frac}\left(\frac{a + b + 1}{2}\right)
$$

At first I thought $m = \min(m_1, m_2)$, but this would not work for numbers such as $0$ and $0.9$, where $m = 0.95$, not $0.45$.  In the figure below, $m=m_1$.  Hopefully this illustrates what I'm looking for.

[image: Points a and b on an interval from 0 to 1, exclusive. m1 is the closest midpoint, the other is labeled m2.]

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question, I came up with a solution.  However, it might not be the best solution, so I'm still interested to see if there's a simpler one.  I came up with this equation for $m$ that works for all the values I could think of testing.

$$
m = \begin{cases}
    m_1 & \left| a - b \right| < 0.5 \\
    m_2 & \left| a - b \right| \geq 0.5 \\
\end{cases}
$$